# How can I show the image which is taken from restfull api using angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have api which is return the image whether it is present in the database or not, I have to use that api with angularJs to display that image in my UI.

I have to pass userid and check corresponding to that userid whether the image of that user is present or not,  if present that display that image otherwise display dummy image.

**AngularJs Code for taking image from server**

```
QAApp.controller('imgCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  // id is userid.
  $scope.image = function (id) {
       var request = $http({
                          method: 'GET', 
                          url: server + 'api/image/' + id,
                        });
            request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.response = data;
            console.log($scope.response);
        });
  }


});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="artst-pic pull-left">
      <img src=" " alt="" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: does the http.get return the image url or the image itself ? I'd say, that the backend should decide, if user's image or dummy image should be shown, by just passing the url

Comment: http.get return image itself....I am checking locally like "http://localhost:8000/api/image/7" it will return image not url...

Comment: and this will return nothing, if no image available ?

Comment: yes, then it will return json response like that.."{"error":true,"details":"No image."}"

Comment: This is a kinda bad concept, when a rest service returns 2 different media.

It should just return the URL or the image, that much easier to handle.

Comment: Can I use ng-show to display the image like that ng-view = "image(id)"....please see in my code which I have post....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, with `<img>` tag you need to use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of src

then, you can bind $scope.imageUrl with ng-src like:

```
<img ng-src="imageUrl" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

now in your controller:

```
request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if(data.imagePath)
    {
        $scope.imageUrl = data.imagePath;
    } else {
        $scope.imageUrl = 'http://some/defaulturl.png';
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not working, please tell me the another alternative method, where I can pass the userid in a function and get the image and the display....

Comment: the user said they are getting an image, not an image path

Answer (score 2):

You can interpolate your image url into the template like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{ imageUrl }}" />
```

There's no need to do AJAX request to get the image. `<img />` tag will do this for you

Comment: but you need a seperation due to the possible json return, when the  user image is not existing

Comment: if an image is broken it will fire its onerror event. handle that: <img src="someimage.jpg" onerror="this.style.display='none';" />

Comment: I didnt have imgurl, I have to pass the userID and take the image of that particular userId image and this is I am getting by "http://localhost:8000/api/image/id", id is varying every time, what I am thinking is, write a function in which I pass the "id" of that user and take the image as I previously post my code...but I am not able to please tell how can I do this....

Comment: You can something like this: `<img ng-src="{{ getImageUrl(userId) }}" />`, where `getImageUrl` is a function in your `$scope`. You can do whatever you need inside the function, handle for possibly a missing image and return some kind of default one, etc.